On tap not working on background notification by local notification with firebase background message
I am receiving notification from firebase title and body is null in notification object so that I can display notification with my custom data with flutter local notification. Issue is I want to open chat screen on background notification tap but it is not working, My app is opening not chat screen.
main.dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future _firebaseBackgroundMessaging(RemoteMessage message) async {
  BackgroundNotificationService().initNotification(message);
}

BackgroundNotificationService class
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onBackgroundNotificationTap(NotificationResponse message) async {
  print(message.payload); // nothing will print
  var data = jsonDecode(message.payload ?? '{}');
  if (data != null) {
    Get.to(() => ChatScreen(
          name: data['senderNumber'],
          roomId: data['roomId'],
          userNumber: data['senderNumber'],
          receiverId: '',
          isGroup: data['isGroup'] == '1' ? true : false,
          userProfile: data['profile_pic'],
          userBio: data['bio'],
        ));
  }
}

class BackgroundNotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterNotification =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  late List<CustomContactsModel> contacts;

  void initNotification(RemoteMessage event) async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();

    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(0)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
      Hive.registerAdapter(CustomContactsModelAdapter());
      Hive.registerAdapter(RoomsAdapter());
      Hive.registerAdapter(MessagesAdapter());
      Hive.registerAdapter(MediaModelAdapter());
    }

    await LocalDatabase.openLocalDb();
    LocalDatabase.saveBackgroundUnreadMessages(event.data['roomId']);
    contacts = LocalDatabase.getAllCustomContacts();
    CustomContactsModel? contact =
        contacts.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.id == event.data['senderId']);

    await initializeService(
        contact?.displayName ?? event.data['senderNumber'],
        event.data['roomId'],
        event.data['senderNumber'],
        event.data['isGroup'] == '1' ? true : false,
        event.data['profile_pic'],
        event.data['bio']);

    if (event.data['isGroup'] == '0') {
      sendNotification(
          title: contact?.displayName ?? event.data['senderNumber'],
          body: EncryptionHelper().decryptMessage(event.data['body'] ?? ''),
          id: event.hashCode,
          data: event.data);
    } else {
      sendNotification(
          title: event.data['groupName'],
          body: EncryptionHelper().decryptMessage(event.data['body'] ?? ''),
          id: event.hashCode,
          data: event.data);
    }
  }

  Future<void> initializeService(String userName, String roomId,
      String userNumber, bool isGroup, profile, bio) async {
    var androidInitializeSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializeSettings,
    );
    await _flutterNotification.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
            onBackgroundNotificationTap);
  }

  void sendNotification(
      {int id = 0,
      required String title,
      required String body,
      required Map<String, dynamic> data}) {
    var androidNotificationDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      '1',
      'message',
      priority: Priority.max,
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    var notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    _flutterNotification.show(id, title, body, notificationDetails,
        payload: jsonEncode(data));
  }
}

